# How to filter objects in Django by time since last 24 hours?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Assuming there's a starting time from `00:00` to `00:00` every day, how best are Django objects filtered by time,  based on the current day? I initially came up with this:

```
from django.utils import timezone


yesterday = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(1)
qs = Foo.objects.filter(date__gte=yesterday)

##

yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
qs = Foo.objects.filter(date__gte=yesterday)
```

However, this is not particularly right. I would prefer time starting exactly from `00:00` to `timezone.now()` -so something like `Foo.objects.filter(date__range=[00:00, timezone.now()])` Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `date` field is actually a `datetime`.

If you need all records with `date` containing todays date, you can use `__date`:

```py
qs = Foo.objects.filter(date__date=timezone.now())
```

If you need, for example, all yesterdays records, but with time not greater than `timezone.now()`, this way:

```py
qs = Foo.objects.filter(
    date__date=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(1),
    date__lte=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(1)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yevgeniy Kosmak's answer is correct, use `datetime_field__date=` filter.

Here are [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date)

Also you can use `date/datetime - timedelta()` pattern with others arguments in timedelta, like

```
timedelta(
    days=50,
    seconds=27,
    microseconds=10,
    milliseconds=29000,
    minutes=5,
    hours=8,
    weeks=2
)
```

docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)